# ObjectDataSource and FormView: how to add UI edition behaviour from business layer

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource, business-logic, formview

I'm using an ObjectDataSource and a FormView.

In the FormView I have a set of controls. When the FormView is in edition, I have in particular a ComboBox and a TextBox which are related as follows: 
when the ComboBox takes some special values, the TextBox must be read only or not.

For the moment I get that behaviour as follows:  the ComboBox triggers a postback when its selected item is changed and in the 'OnPreRender' of my page I get the value of the ComboBox and update the Readonly property of the TextBox accordingly.

What I don't like with this method is that I don't use my object model which is consumed by the ObjectDataSource. The problem is simply that when the FormView is in edition there does not seem to be a way to get the instance of the object which is being edited. The 'DataItem' is null and I haven't found any way to automatically build a new object from the values in the controls to pass it to my business layer. Of course I could do the whole job myself by getting explicitly all the values in the controls, but that's not nice.

Has anybody ever met such a scenario ? Any ideas on how to get a clean design ?

Answer (score 0):

How about using DataItemIndex or DataKey? I would probably use DataKey and then use the business method to look up for the object for the key.

Comment: Yes, but I will get the object without the ongoing modifications made by the user. And to get these modifications I'll have to read data in all controls, e.g., myBusinessObject.Property1 = controlX.Text; myBusinessObject.Property2 = controlY.SelectedValue;... . If I had an automatic way of doing that that would be great.